# How do I set an image for some but not all nodes in a TreeView?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, treeview

I have a `TreeView` windows forms control with an `ImageList`, and I want some of the nodes to display images, but the others to not have images.

I *don't* want a blank space where the image should be.  I *don't* want an image that looks like the lines that the TreeView would draw if it didn't have an ImageList.  How do I get it to draw images for some items and not others, without resorting to clumsy hacks like that?

Comment: Could you specify if this is used in a web or winforms app, please?

Comment: Accepted answer should be the one by Aussie Ash, below.  Tested, and it works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I tried this once and I don't think it is possible.

If you try to set both `ImageKey` and `ImageIndex` to "not set" values the control just defaults `ImageIndex` to 0. The following code:

```
treeView.ImageKey = "Value";
Debug.WriteLine(treeView.ImageIndex);
treeView.ImageKey = null;
Debug.WriteLine(treeView.ImageIndex);
treeView.ImageIndex = -1;
Debug.WriteLine(treeView.ImageIndex);
```

Produces output:

```
-1
0
0
```

This kind of tells you that the control developers wanted to make sure that there was always a default image. That just leaves you with the hack options I'm afraid.

Comment: Thats because the treeView.ImageIndex setter contains this (I used ILSpy): if (value == -1)value = 0;if (value < 0)throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("ImageIndex", SR.GetString("InvalidLowBoundArgumentEx", new object[]{"ImageIndex",value.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture),0.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)}));
....

Comment: Just include a blank 1 pixel x 1 pixel icon and load the nodes that you don't want an icon, with this.

Answer (score 12):

You need to set `ImageIndex` and `SelectedImageIndex` to a number that is higher than the number of values in your `ImageList`. For example, if you create this node and add it to your `TreeView`:

```
TreeNode node1 = new TreeNode(string.Empty, 12, 12); // imageList1.Count = 5
```

you will have an invisible `TreeNode` inserted into your `TreeView`. I changed the background color of my `TreeView` and it was still invisible.

(I googled this for some time, and I eventually found the answer here: http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/DotNet/microsoft.public.dotnet.framework.windowsforms/2006-09/msg00322.html)

Comment: Is this documented by MS somewhere? I would be cautious using this kind of technique as is sounds like the kind of thing that may not be kept compatible in future versions of the framework.

Comment: Invisible nodes are not very useful. If there is text, you'll see that the space for the image is still reserved, blank or not.

Answer (score 11):

What I have chosen to do is to use an image of dots for those `TreeView` nodes that are not supposed to have an image.

[image: TreeNode with image dots]

I add this image as the last image in the list, and if the item is not supposed to have an image I set it to `ImageList.Images.Count-1`

Comment: I don't suppose you have this image somewhere do you? :-)

Comment: Take a screen shot and modify it to suit your purpose

Comment: That is what I ended up doing, was just being lazy in case you had one lying around :-)

Comment: For future reference, I made a little GitHub project with instructions and an image (16x16) to do this:https://github.com/cmbankester/tree-view-no-image-dots/blob/master/no-image-dots.png

Answer (score 11):

I found that using StateImageList on the TreeView instead of ImageList will only show the image when StateImageIndex on the TreeNode is equal or greater than 0

Comment: It seems to be limited to 14 images.

Comment: Brilliant yet simple workaround (if you only need <= 15 icons)

Answer (score 3):

**This will draw the `TreeNode` text where the image should have been, getting rid of the white space.**

You'll need to set the `TreeView`'s `DrawMode` property to `OwnerDrawText`. You can find the `DrawMode` property in the properties panel.

Next when you add a node, set it's `ImageIndex` and `SelectedImageIndex` greater than the value of your `yourImageListName.Images.Count` value. This is so no image will be drawn, but there will still be that white space you don't want.

Now to get rid the white space. Add a handle for the treeviews `DrawNode` event. This can be done by going to the treeviews property panel and clicking the Icon in the panel that looks like a lighting bolt, then scroll till you see the text `DrawNode`, double click it.

Now you just copy and paste this into the created method

```
if (e.Node.ImageIndex >= e.Node.TreeView.ImageList.Images.Count) // if there is no image
{
    int imagewidths = e.Node.TreeView.ImageList.ImageSize.Width;
    int textheight = TextRenderer.MeasureText(e.Node.Text, e.Node.NodeFont).Height;
    int x = e.Node.Bounds.Left - 3 - imagewidths / 2;
    int y = (e.Bounds.Top + e.Bounds.Bottom) / 2+1;

    Point point = new Point(x - imagewidths/2, y - textheight/2); // the new location for the text to be drawn

    TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, e.Node.Text, e.Node.NodeFont, point, e.Node.ForeColor);
}
else // drawn at the default location
    TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, e.Node.Text, e.Node.TreeView.Font, e.Bounds, e.Node.ForeColor);
```

Comment: Does not quite work. Selection is still drawn on it's original location (dislocated to the right relative to nodes without images).

Comment: Your answer helped me, but I tidied up the logic. It's just `Bounds.Left` that you need to manipulate to hide the whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Hei bro, i found a way.
Set the first image as an empty image, like this...

```
TreeView treeView = new TreeView();
treeView.ImageList.Images.Add(new Bitmap(1,1));
```

So, the index 0 is an empty image.
I hope this helps

Comment: This method leaves a blank space, contrary to what the original poster asked for.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue and solved it by iterating the nodes that I wanted to have no icon and setting the ImageIndex and SelectedImageIndex properties to values higher than the ImageList **AFTER** all of the nodes had been already been added to the TreeView. Setting these properties before all of the other nodes were added resulted in only the first one not having the icon.