# Preventing image on TreeView root node, and preventing selected node from defaulting to image 0

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, treeview

I have a `TreeView` with a `ImageList` populated in run time. This `TreeView` has only a root node and everything else is a direct child of that root node.

### I have 2 problems:

1) My root node have a image, and I don't want.

```
//I tried to put -1, because this property has a default 0 (non-nullable int)
this.Nodes[0].ImageIndex = -1;
//But nothing happened.
```

2) The selected node always change the image to the index 0, it shouldn't

```
//Again, changing to -1 did nothing.
this.SelectedImageIndex = -1;
```

Example:

[image]

Comment: For your first issue, take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/261660/how-do-i-set-an-image-for-some-but-not-all-nodes-in-a-treeview It looks like an image is required for all nodes if you set it, looking at the setter it sets the value to 0 if it's -1 and throws an index out of bounds exception if it's less than that.  You might be able to get your desired functionality through a messy hack, but the best bet would be to create your own UserControl

Comment: Setting the index to `-1` before setting to something else will not throw a exception. But thanks. Maybe it's time for a own user control.

Comment: setting it to `-1` works because the setter will set the value to `0` but if you set it to something else e.g. `-2` it will throw an exception.  A UserControl would be the cleanest way, but looking at some of the other answers in the question I posted above you might be able to achieve what you're looking for. Take a look at the answer user1887120 posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get a blank .ico file (You can use this one :http://knowledgebase.twocoders.de/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/blank.ico) and add it to your image list. Set the image to the index of the blank.ico. The end result should will be a list view node without an icon. Here is an example of what it looks like:

[image: This is a picture]

Comment: That will do, shame is the white space that i'll got because of the size of my images. Thanks.